# C# regex to accept current/voltage value

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex which can validate a input string if it is valid voltage or current.
Required format will be any number followed by 'V' or 'A' is valid.

I was thinking to split string and validate it but it not robust solution and hard to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
^[0-9]+\s?[vaVA]$
```

Another, more compact, expression would be

```
^\d+\s?[vaVA]$
```

Or, you could simply include the characters `[va]` and mark the expressing as case insensitive.

If you don’t want to accept input with space between the number and the unit, leave the `\s?` out. So the expression would be

```
^\d+[vaVA]$
```

If you want to allow negative numbers, include the dash as optional in front of the number, like so:

```
^-?\d+\s?[vaVA]$
```

And if you would like to accept decimal values:

```
 ^-?\d+(\.\d+)?\s?[vaVA]$
```

Since the question is marked C#, make sure to either escape the RegEx definitions or use the @ operator with the string (ie. `@"^\d+[avAV]$"`)

**Update**

To strictly match, you can use the start of line(`^`) and end of line anchors (`$`) respectively. I’ve updated the example expression to include these.

Comment: I have tried this Mike, but it accept all string which can end with combination of V and A. My requirement is, it should accept either A or V at a time.

Comment: It also accepts number with mixed character followed by A and V.

Comment: Can you give an example of the string that is incorrectly matched?

Comment: @Dipak maybe you need `^\d+[vaVA]$` which is basically the 3rd option Mike gave with the addition of the beginning and ending anchors

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted... unless test cases are given to show where it fails... it's a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this
/\d+v/gi
string c = "12V" // number to validate

if(c.match(/\d+v/gi)!null)
{
number validated
}
else
{
not valid
}

```
 /\d+v|\d+a/i
```

`\d` => select all number
`+` > select all numbers till it finds a not numeric value
`v`=>select v
`/i` => makes the match case insensitive
`|` => or operator

Comment: Why do you use the global flag? What about current mesurement (in ampere)?

Comment: for ampere try this /\d+v|\d+a/gi

Comment: you can do also without global,

Comment: global it needs only when there are more rows, if you only have to check 1 row for time then it doesn't need